# 'npm run build' in linked dependency breaks the running react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-scripts

it seems that rebuilding a local linked dependency breaks the main package that is running with `react-scripts-ts start` with a "not found" for file `dist/index.js` of the linked module.

This is not happening in Mac OSX where after linked local module is rebuild, the running react-app automatically reloads with no problems.

In Ubuntu you have to stop the react app and run "npm run start" again.

Any clue?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling all the dependencies and running npm start ?

Comment: Are you there are no multiple node version issue between your machines ?

Comment: @Muljayan yes, many times

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini no, one single node version